# Howto use keycloak, oauth2 and dashboard - Error 403 invalid request - invalid scope

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, keycloak, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to use Keycloak with Oauth2 to secure kubernetes-dashboard. I found several post about this error, but none was specific for my problem. maybe i just miss a simple step ..

so far i followed this guide: https://jamesveitch.com/homelab/02.idam/02.keycloak/

Keycloak is installed at the kubernetes cluster within the namespace keycloak.
Kubernetes-dashboard is installed within the namespace kubernetes-dashboard.

Keycloak is reachable under auth.mydomain.com and the dashboard should be reachbale under dashboard.mydomain.com.

I have created a user "test" and assigned a group kubernetes-admin which i would use to grant access to the dashboard.

I configured Keycloak like this:

1. Created a new realm "dev"
2. Created a User test and a group kubernetes-admin
3. Created a new client "dashboard"

   - Access Type: confidential
   - Service Account enabled: on
   - Valid Redirect Url: https://dashboard.mydomain.com/oauth/callback
   - Created a Mapper for groups (Type: Group Membership, TokenClaimName:groups)

For Clusterbinding of kubernetes-admin i use this yaml:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: keycloak-admin-group
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  # NOTE: This is a super administrator and can do everything.
  # Consider a dedicated role in your actual operation.
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: kubernetes-admin
```

For the Configuration of OAuth2 and Ingress i use:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/use-port-in-redirects: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
  name: dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dashboard.mydomain.com
    secretName: dashboard.mydomain.com-tls
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
        path: /
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dashboard.mydomain.com
    secretName: dashboard.mydomain.com-tls
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=keycloak
        - --client-id=dashboard
        - --client-secret=a27b97fb-eafc-420c-88ba-8017beb54180
        - --login-url=https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        - --redeem-url=https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token
        - --validate-url=https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
        - --keycloak-group=kubernetes-admin
        - --email-domain=*
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --reverse-proxy=true
        - --pass-access-token=true
        - --set-xauthrequest=true
        - --ssl-insecure-skip-verify=true
        - --ssl-upstream-insecure-skip-verify=true
        - --cookie-domain=.mydomain.com
        - --whitelist-domain=.mydomain.com
        - --upstream=https://kubernetes-dashboard.kubernetes-dashboard.svc.cluster.local
        # Register a new application
        # https://github.com/settings/applications/new
        env:
        # docker run -ti --rm python:3-alpine python -c 'import secrets,base64;     print(base64.b64encode(base64.b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(16))));'
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: ekNsWlN6MkphVVVmTnNZUTBEZnZVQT09
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
```

This yaml file is used for a development enviroment with letsencrypt-staging and should ignore ssl errors.

What works is, that i can open https://dashboard.mydomain.com/oauth2/signin and press Sigin with Keycloak. But next i am redirect to 403 Permission Error Page..
The oauth2 logs says: Error on /oauth2/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=Invalid+scopes

Please keep in Mind that i would like to use a upstream the kubernetes dashboard service.. thats why i try here as upstream https://kubernetes-dashboard.kubernetes-dashboard.svc.cluster.local.. hope this is right ??

How can I fix this ?? Any Ideas ?
Is Keycloak configured correctly ?

Some sites say to use (https://* and http://* as valid urls.. tried without luck)

Hope someone can help.. I did spend a lot time to get this work so far.. but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to handle this error:

1. First, we need to change the URL within keycloak to  https://dashboard.mydomain.com/*
2. Under the dashboard - Mapper - groups deactivate the full group path ..
   This removes the leading slash of groups within your token ( you can check at Client Sope - Evaluate)
   This is needed for the oauth2 parameter --keycloak-group=kubernetes-admin
3. Create a Client Scope "Users" under the dev realm - at Client Scopes with default values
4. Now change to the second Tab "Default Client Scope" under Client Scopes and assign "Users" as Default Client Scope
5. Add this Client Scope "Users" under  Client -> Dashboard - Client Scope
6. Add the -scope parameter to the oauth2 development : --scope=users

The upstream is correct assigend in above sample to access the dashboard directly within the cluste. So no change needed there.

After this you should be able to open the dashboard without errors.
But i still have a problem that the bearer token is sent, but currently not used to login automatically..  you still have to paste your token.. So i still investigate to get this work..